# Trying to display data from an SQL database using vbscript

Tags: asp.net, sql, vbscript, html

I am trying to set up a connection to my SQL server inside of a VBScript.

Whenever I have a connection to my SQL server there is an error on the webpage that says "There was a problem processing the URL" and to contact the administrator.

I know my connection string is correct because it works on all the others pages.

Here is the code I am using so far to set up the SQL connection

```
Const SQL_Connection_String = "Provider=sqloledb;SERVER=SQLPROD;DATABASE=MyDataBase;UID=MyUsername;PWD=MyPassword;"
    Set SQLConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    SQLConnection.provider = "ADODB.Connection"
    Set SQLConnectionRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
```

From what I know this should be a valid way of setting up the connection in a VBscript. I have not really found any good documentation on configuring these connections.

What I would like to know is: am I setting up the connection correctly, and Is there some strategy I could use to troubleshoot this? Meaning I'd like to be able to have a print statement that returns true or false if the connection was successful. I would also like to somehow print the contents of my reader to see if it has read from the database and if it read what I wanted it to read.

Thanks for any help. I'm using VBscript and ASP.net for the first time so I don't know any of the subtlties.

Comment: welcome to SO. to help us help you, it would be useful to see the stacktrace for your error

Comment: Unfortunately to include the stack trace would include about 107 errors still remaining on the rest of the website. I'm still new to using Visual Basic and I'm not sure how I could just isolate the problems from this single page

Comment: You really should look at doing new web sites in ASP.NET instead of classic ASP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your

```
SQLConnection.provider = "ADODB.Connection"
```

is definitely wrong. As you specify the provider in the connection string, there is a (small) chance that deleting that line, will make your script 'work'.

**UPDATE**

(1) If you have problems connecting to your database, use [this excellent source](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) to get started on theory and samples, create an empty file (e.g. constr.udl), start it, and use the GUI to specify/test your connection. Leaving the dialog will save the connection string in the file, from where you can pick it up via a decent (Unicode enabled) editor.
[image: using .udl file]

(2) If you have too many errors on your ASP page, extract the (simplified) database code to a commandline .vbs script; that way you can focus on one foe (and deal with second one when you are sure, your SELECTs return the desired data).

(3) If you have problems with specific SQL statements/features/expressions, study the docs; in this case look into your favorite SQL book or follow Google to [LIKE (according to the horse)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx). JOIN may be a candidate too. Then use (2) to start from simple statements, proceed to more complex ones **after** you have mastered the seemingly boring.
("Table2.Date LIKE '2011'" may work or not, depending on the type and content of the Date column (and isn't Date a reserved/key word?)

(While Derek will surely read an answer to another of his question, other poeple starting here will probably profit from reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11109308/603855) too.)

Comment: I commented it out and the webpagew still acts the same.

Comment: I think this may have been a red herring. that particular line of code can be deleted though. The real problem is the reader I created to read from the actual database. The Code looks like this { SQL_Command_String = "SELECT * FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 WHERE Table1.ID = '5' AND Table2.Date LIKE '2011'"

    Set SQL_Reader = SQLConnection.Execute(SQL_Command_String)
    WHILE NOT SQL_Reader.EOF} My thoughts are I am not using the LIKE keyword correctly for SQL

Comment: I'll keep that in mind I still have to get the entire script working correctly

Answer (score 1):

Here's some example code for scripting ADO:

```
Set SQLConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
SQLConnection.Open ConnectionString

Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
rs.Open "SELECT SYSTEM_USER AS Username, session_id, auth_scheme, net_transport, client_net_address FROM sys.dm_exec_connections WHERE (@@SPID = session_id)", SQLConnection 

' Loop through each record until there are no more
While NOT rs.EOF
    ' Loop through each field
    For Each field In rs.Fields
        output.Write field.Value & " "
    next

    rs.MoveNext
    output.WriteLine
Wend
```

Comment: the code creates "SQLConnection", but uses "conn" in the .Open call. Where do "ConnectionString" and "output" come from?

Comment: Oops, `conn` should be `SQLConnection`. I've edited to fix that. `output` can be anything, that supports a Write method and is only meant to show how you can make use of `field.Value`. In my case, I was using the code in a VBS file so there's a `Set output = WScript.StdOut` line.