# I am getting an when retrieving info from Active Directory and attempting to insert into DB

Tags: vbscript, active-directory

I am not real sure what I am doing wrong here.

I am trying to retrieve some values from Active Directory and insert them into our sql server database.

I keep getting error on line 23 "Provider: Unspecified Error"

This is line 23 --> Set adoRecordset = adoCommand.Execute

Below is the code I am using and thanks:

```
    '==============
Set adoCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set adoConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
adoConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
adoConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
adoCommand.ActiveConnection = adoConnection
 ' Search entire Active Directory domain.
Set objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
strDNSDomain = objRootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")
strBase = "<LDAP://" & strDNSDomain & ">"
strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))"
'strFilter = "(&(objectClass=computer)(cn=" & strComputer & "))"
' Comma delimited list of attribute values to retrieve.
'strAttributes = "sAMAccountName,cn"
strAttributes = "employeeID,name,givenName,sname"
' Construct the LDAP syntax query.
strQuery = strBase & ";" & strFilter & ";" & strAttributes & ";subtree"
adoCommand.CommandText = strQuery
adoCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 100
adoCommand.Properties("Timeout") = 30
adoCommand.Properties("Cache Results") = False
' Run the query.
Set adoRecordset = adoCommand.Execute  **<--Error pointing to this line**
' ********  SET UP DB CONNECTION **********
Set dbConn = createobject("ADODB.Connection")
dbConn.ConnectionString = "driver=Sql Server;server=serverName;uid=myuser;pwd=mypwd;database=myDB"
dbConn.Open
' *****************************************
strDetails = ""
' Enumerate the resulting recordset.
Do Until adoRecordset.EOF
    ' Retrieve values and display.
      strEmpID = adoRecordset.Fields("employeeID").Value
      strName = adoRecordset.Fields("name").Value
      strfname = adoRecordset.Fields("givenName").Value
      strlname = adoRecordset.Fields("sname").Value
' ******* INSERT INTO DB *************
      dbConn.Execute "INSERT INTO myTable Values('" & strEmpID & "','" & strName & "','" & strfname & "','" & strlname & "')"
' ************************************
      ' Move to the next record in the recordset.
    adoRecordset.MoveNext
Loop
' Clean up.
adoRecordset.Close
Set adoRecordset = Nothing
adoConnection.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string to the MS SQL Server - `"driver=Sql Server; ..."` - looks fishy. Using [the source for connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/), I would expect something like `"Provider= ..."`, but without further info about versions and access strategy (odbc, oledb, ...) it's difficult to tell.

I have written about using an .udl file to experiment with connection strings in an GUI [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11105750/603855).

Comment: Hi Ehhehard,

Thanks for that nice link. I created udl and used the link on my code but still same error. 

Looking at the error, the connectionstring is on line 26 but the error is on line 23. I am suspecting the error is looking for something above the error line. Could you please let me know what specific info you might need?

I am trying to use the code to point to our Active Directory, retrieve some data and insert the data into the db.