# MySQL OLEDB connection string in VB Script?

Tags: mysql, vbscript

I need a Connection String to Connect mysql by using OleDB Provider in vB sCRIPT

Note:I have already Done with ODBC Driver So only Oledb Provider String is appreciable.

Comment: You did not even search for an answer *once*. Not a single attempt to solve your question on your own. You're pretty lazy.

Answer (score 0):

[connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql#net-framework-data-provider-for-ole-db) has just about every connection string you'll ever need.

Comment: ad = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")      'create and open ODBC connection 

        ad.ConnectionString = ("Provider=OleMySql.MySqlSource.1;Data Source=localhost;User ID=root;Password=permitsensys;Initial Catalog=db")

        ad.Open()

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer (update)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11105750/603855) which shows how to use an .udl file to set up and experiment with a connectionstring in a GUI (after some research at connectionstrings.com).