# Why won't this VBScript run on Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012?

Tags: windows, vbscript

### Problem

A past administrator wrote a VBScript that connected to a Visual FoxPro database and extracted some data to be collect by another application. I completely didn't realise that we still relied heavily on this as I had no knowledge of it.

It ran perfectly ok on Windows Server 2008, but now we have migrated to Windows Server 2012 it doesn't. It also won't run on my own Windows 8 client showing the error message:

`Error: Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.`

I have been through Programs & Features on the old Windows Server 2008 and see nothing related to Visual FoxPro databases installed.

I have no VBScript experience (although I can read this script and understand what it is doing etc.).

### Script

I'll include the connection part only as that is clearly the problem.

```
Dim sDir : sDir = "\\FileServer\Server VFP Dynamic\Data"
Dim sCS  : sCS  = Join(Array( _
        "Provider=vfpoledb" _
      , "Data Source=" & sDir _
      , "Collating Sequence=general" _
), ";")
Dim oCN : Set oCN = CreateObject("ADODB.CONNECTION")
```

### Update 1

I downloaded and installed the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro 9.0 at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839 and I see this listed in Programs & Features but the error message continues. I also did a restart etc.

[image]

I checked the Windows Server 2008 where the VBScript continues to work and Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro 9.0 is not listed in Programs & Features there, so I would suggest it is not this that is making it work there.

Comment: You surely forgot to mention that you are now running this on a 64-bit operating system.  There is no 64-bit provider, you need to execute the script with the 32-bit scripting host.  Use c:\windows\syswow64\cscript.exe

Answer (score 2):

The VP Ole driver is found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839). Supported Operating Systems:

> Windows 2000 Service Pack 3, Windows 98, Windows ME, Windows Server
>   2003, Windows XP

so do some research(start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xzsac67%28VS.80%29.aspx))/tests - especially wrt 32/64 bit issues - whether it is possible to use it on your OS.

**Update:**

To check the sanity of the install and of the connection string (provider=vfpoledb.1 ?), follow advice about using .udl file from [here](http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~VFPOleDBProvider) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11105750/603855).